# Why can't I change my Buffer Map units?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

My problem is that my CRS will not change. I have looked at all the other posted questions regarding a similar problem. However hopefully the screen shots provided will indicate my issue.

**Figure 1** --> I downloaded a shapefile with the orginial CRS of *OSGB 1936 / British National Grid*

[image: Figure 1]

**Figure 2** --> The data plots bird densities and I want to create a buffer around the *selected feature* (yellow point) with the **Map units** selected as either **Meters** or **Kilometers**

[image]

**Figure 3** --> This indicates that in its Original CRS form the `Buffer` will display the *Map units* in **Meters**

[image]

**Figure 4** --> I know I need to change the default CRS, so I click on the data point --> `Export` --> `Save Feature as`

[image]

**Figure 5** --> I change the default CRS from *OSGB 1936 / British National Grid* to *EPSG:4326 - WGS 84* and save it

[image]

**Figure 6** --> [image]

**Figure 7** --> This identifies the bottom shapefile (is the orginal), the middle (is the saved shapefile in the new CRS) and the top shapefile (I uploaded manually, however is the new shapefile CRS as well)

[image]

**Figure 8** --> When I now open the buffer and input the new shapefile in the WSG84 CRS which I require. the distance Is only available in *degrees*. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Are my CRS projections not changing? I am confused if they are not as my newly changes CRS shapefiles are data points lie in the exact same position as the original data.

[image]

Comment: you changed the projection from metres to degrees - so it has changed. Your points will always be in the same place as QGIS reprojects them to the project projection (EPSG:27700?) - stop before step 4 and all is fine

Comment: And the data will be accurate and provide reliable data?

Comment: So long as your data is in Great Britain (or near by) it is hard to find a better projection.

Comment: Ok it is. The only question I have to your answer, and I apologies as I am still a beginner. I did what you said and stopped at step 4. However I do need the data in WSG84 and Meters. not EPSG:27700, So are you saying its fine to stay in that projection as that's reliable for around UK areas, or it needs to be changed as changing it also changes the map units

Comment: There is no such thing as a WGS84 projection in metres. Once you have buffered in EPSG:27700 you can convert to WGS84 (EPSG:4326) and have your buffers be in degrees.

Comment: Thankyou for clearing this up for me. To clarify to convert after buffering all i ned to do is export the feature, change the CRS an save that?

Comment: that's right exactly as you do above. QGIS will still reproject it to the project CRS for you so it will be in the right place.